# Html5 mp4 video freezes IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I have a html5 video on my site and all was working well until client gave me a new video to replace the old one. The new video crashes Internet Explorer (IE10 and IE11 - haven't tried others). When trying to play, a second of video is shown then whole site freezes and a pop-up tells me it's not responding.

No other browser is affected.

Have tried transcoding video in Handbrake to make sure it's using H.264 codec, but still no luck.

All other videos on site work fine in IE.

Has anyone got any suggestions that I can try?

Ps. Sorry, but can't share the video file as it's confidential to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops - found out it was not IE but Avast (anti virus) add on that was freezing video.
Disabled Avast and video played as normal.

Still don't know why it only affected one video.